# Symfony2 Create a Post calls ShowAction

Tags: forms, symfony, redirect, controller, render

I am "transplanting" my old website code into the new Symfony2.6. I have a Controller to render a form and create posts as in a blog. Then it is submited (POST method) in a second controller once it is valid. When I call the route to initialize the controller, for some reason I ignore, it also calls the ShowAction($slug), and it fails since the post it is not yet created and hence it does not have any $slug parameter. Why is it calling this showAction? Despite I type the url to just display the form.

Here is the error log at the line that starts the failure:

```
1. in src/Blog/BlogBundle/Services/PostManager.php at line 80
2. at PostManager ->findBySlug ('create_post') in src/Blog/BlogBundle/Controller PostController.php at line 55  
3. at PostController ->ShowAction ('create_post')
4. at call_user_func_array (array(object(PostController), 'ShowAction'), array('create_post')) in app/bootstrap.php.cache at line 3020
```

I do not want to call the ShowAction.

Here is the controller code:

```
 /**
    * Show a Post
   *
 * @param string $slug
 *
 * @throws NotFoundHttpException
 * @return array
 *
 * @Route("/{slug}")
 * @Template()
 */
public function ShowAction($slug)
{
    $post = $this->getPostManager()->findBySlug($slug);
    $form_comment = $this->createForm(new CommentType());

    return array(
        'post' => $post,
        'form_comment' => $form_comment->createView()
    );
}

/**
 * Displays a form to create a new Post entity.
 *
 * @Route("/new_post", name="_blog_backend_post_new")
 * @Template()
 */
public function newAction()
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new PostType(), new PostModel(new Post()));

    return array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    );
}

/**
 * Creates a new Post entity.
 *
 * @Route("/create_post", name="_blog_backend_post_create")
 * @Method("POST")
 * @Template("BlogBundle:Backend/Post:new.html.twig")
 */
public function createAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $form = $this->createForm(new PostType(), new PostModel(new Post()));
    $formHandler = new PostHandler($form, $request, new Post(), $em);
    if ($formHandler->process()) {
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('_blog_backend_post'));
    }

    return array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    );
}
```

I do not know if its necessary but here are the involved templates:
* @Template("BlogBundle:Backend/Post:new.html.twig"):

```
{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}

{% block content %}
    <form class="well" action="{{ url('_blog_backend_post_create') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
        {% include 'BlogBundle:Backend/Post:edit.form.html.twig' with {'form': form } %}
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

BlogBundle:Backend/Post:edit.form.html.twig:

```
{% if form_errors(form) %}
<div class="alert alert-block alert-error fade in form-errors">
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
</div>
{% endif %}
<p>
<label for="">Title</label>
{% if form_errors(form.title) %}
<div class="alert alert-block alert-error fade in form-errors">
    {{ form_errors(form.title) }}
</div>
{% endif %}
{{ form_widget(form.title, { 'attr': {'class': 'w100'} }) }}
</p>
<p>
<label for="">Body</label>
{% if form_errors(form.body) %}
<div class="alert alert-block alert-error fade in form-errors">
    {{ form_errors(form.body) }}
</div>
{% endif %}
{{ form_widget(form.body, { 'attr': {'class': 'w100'} }) }}
</p>
<p>
<button class="btn" type="submit">Save</button>
<a class="btn" href="{{ url('_blog_backend_post') }}">Cancel</a>
</p>
{{ form_rest(form) }}
```

What I am missing and how can I correct it? Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Why you don't use the same function for new/edit form, and also handle it after submit?

Comment: I want to improve it and the old ones are not useful in this case. However the ones Im using now are the very same, so the problem I think is within the controller that calls first the showAction and not only the newAction

Comment: Create a single route that handles both new & edit action. If "$slug" is null, you create new object, otherwise you update the current one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The router matches the first route possible, in this case "/{slug}" where slug="create_post".

There are at least two solutions, where the first is the easiest, the second is the one I recommend:

- Cut/Paste your showAction to the bottom of your file, in that case router will match /create_post to the createAction first
- You can exclude this like: `@Route("/{slug}", requirements={"slug" = "^(?<!create_post).+"})`

Comment: The error shows that /create_post is the problem.  So why does /new_post appear to work?

Comment: That's because I read this first: "Despite I type the url to just display the form.", and that's the "new_post". But thanks, I changed it correctly

Comment: So what do you think happens if the user types /new_post?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I the slug was interfering with the new action. I added the new requirement and its working now. However its weird it was working in previous symfony releases. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are posting to /create_post which in turn matches the route /{slug}.  slug is being set to 'create_post'.  With the Symfony 2 router the first match wins and thus your showAction method is called.

Consider setting your ShowAction path to: '/show/{slug}'.

Or you could move your ShowAction down to the bottom of your controller file.  That is a bit dangerous because you might forget and add a different action later.  But either way will work.